# play2: FakeRequest().withBody(body) automatically converted to Request[AnyContentAsEmpty] in controller

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I'm working on a play-2.4 project, and wrote a controller like:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class Application extends Controller {
  def index = Action.async { implicit request =>
    Future { Ok(request.body.asJson.get) }
  }
}
```

with `POST  /  controllers.Application.index` in
`conf/routes`.

I checked this worked fine by executing `curl --request POST --header "Content-type: application/json" --data '{"foo":"bar"}' http://localhost:9000/`.

Now I wrote a spec for this controller:

```
package controllers

import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner._
import org.junit.runner._

import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ApplicationSpec extends Specification {
  "Application" should {
    val controller = new Application
    val fakeJson = """{ "foo":"bar" }"""
    val fakeRequest = FakeRequest()
      .withHeaders("Content-type" -> "application/json")
      .withBody(fakeJson)
    val index = controller.index()(fakeRequest).run
    status(index) must equalTo(OK)
  }
}
```

but this resulted in a runtime error:

```
[error]    None.get (Application.scala:11)
[error] controllers.Application$$anonfun$index$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Application.scala:11)
[error] controllers.Application$$anonfun$index$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Application.scala:11)
```

I inserted `println(request.body)` in the controller and found the request body was `AnyContentAsEmpty`, meaning `fakeJson` was removed from `fakeRequest`.

How can I attach a JSON to FakeRequest properly?

*note: Although I can write like `FakeRequest(POST, '/', FakeHeaders(), fakeJson)`, but I think this is not good because controller spec should not handle HTTP methods or routes.

I'll be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a client makes an HTTP POST to your action with a request that *isn't* JSON, `request.body.asJson.get` will throw an exception.

1. `body.asJson` has return type `Option[JsValue]` and it returns a `None` if the request wasn't JSON.
2. Calling `get` on a `None` throws a `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.
3. This exception manifests as Play returning a `500 Internal Server Error`.

You should replace `def index = Action.async ...` with an action that uses a JSON [body parser](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaBodyParsers) instead:

```
import play.api.mvc.BodyParsers.parse

def index = Action.async(parse.json) ...
```

This achieves a few things:

1. It's more self-documenting (the action says "I expect JSON" right there in the method declaration).
2. Play will generate a `400 Bad Request` if the POST wasn't JSON. This is more appropriate than the `500 Internal Server Error` caused by your `None.get`.
3. It will make `request.body` a `JsValue` instead of `AnyContent`. So you can replace `request.body.asJson.get` with simply `request.body`. In general you should avoid calling `Option.get` because it's not safe and there's usually a better way to achieve what you want (using the appropriate body parser happens to be that better way in this case).

Now this test no longer compiles, as opposed to throwing the exception caused by `None.get`:

```
val fakeJson = """{ "foo":"bar" }"""
val fakeRequest = FakeRequest()
  .withHeaders("Content-type" -> "application/json")
  .withBody(fakeJson)
val index = controller.index()(fakeRequest)
status(index) must equalTo(OK)
```

Forcing you to replace it with the version from your answer:

```
val fakeJson = play.api.libs.json.Json.parse("""{ "foo":"bar" }""") 
val fakeRequest = FakeRequest().withBody(fakeJson)              
val index = controller.index()(fakeRequest)                         
status(index) must equalTo(OK)
```

My final suggestion is that you use `Json.obj` to clean up your test:

```
val fakeJson = Json.obj("foo" -> "bar")
```

Comment: Thank you for very detailed answer. I'd like to ask one more thing: Why does the controller with `parse.json` NOT parse the body of `fakeRequest` (that is a string), while it DOES automatically parse the body of `POST` request from client (something like `curl`)? What is the difference?

Comment: UPDATE: changed as your suggestion, but the test does not compile with saying that `index` is an instance of `play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[Array[Byte], play.api.mvc.Result]`, but the compiler requires it being `scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]` as Action.async expects that. I tried to change the test code to `status(index.run)` and that compiled, but came with runtime error (the HTML response said `[Expecting text/json or application/json body]` with status 415). How can I solve this situation?

Comment: `val index = new Application().index()(FakeRequest().withBody(Json.obj("foo" -> "bar")))` followed by `status(index) must equalTo(OK)` works for me (the test compiles and passes).

Comment: Uhh, just worked by replacing `withJsonBody([JsValue])` with `withBody([JsValue])`, as your comment... Very confusing for me. Do you have any idea what is different?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. `withBody` gives you a `FakeRequest[JsValue]` but `withJsonBody` gives you a `FakeRequest[AnyContentAsJson]`. You want the former, because that's the type of request you get from `Action.async(parse.json)`.

Comment: Reading original implementation of playframework and finally got what you meant! Thanks a lot! Learned many lessons from this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

**[SELF-SOLVED]**

Struggling another couple of hours, the problem was solved using `withJsonBody`:

```
"Application" should {                                                
  val controller = new Application                                    
  val fakeJson = play.api.libs.json.Json.parse("""{ "foo":"bar" }""") 
  val fakeRequest = FakeRequest().withJsonBody(fakeJson)              
  val index = controller.index()(fakeRequest)                         
  status(index) must equalTo(OK)                                      
}
```

Any other suggestions are welcome.